# Free bosons with an attractive/repulsive defect

Tags: statistical-mechanics, lattice-model, bosons

Consider a system of non-interacting bosons hopping in a qubic lattice in 2D or 3D. A single site of the lattice is an attractive/repulsive defect. Formally, let $H=-t\sum_{<i,j>}(a_i^\dagger a_j+a_j^\dagger a_i)+\lambda a_0^\dagger a_0$ . The boson number is conserved and since it's a single-particle problem, we can fix the boson number to $1$ for simplicity.

If there are $N=L^D$ sites in the lattice ($D=2,3$), the average of the boson density per site is $1/N$. One would expect that in the groundstate of the system, the boson density at site $0$ is higher/lower than this average, depending on the sign of $\lambda$, and that the deviation from the $1/N$ average decays with the distance to the defect. I know how to calculate the groundstate energy of $H$ using perturbation theory, but how can I calculate groundstate expectation values $<a_i^\dagger a_i>$? How does $|<a_i^\dagger a_i>-1/N|$ decay with the distance between sites $i$ and $0$? Exponentially or power-law?

I'm not necessarily looking for a complete answer to these questions, but I would be grateful for pointers towards techniques that can be used to solve this problem.